# How to delay GameObject Destroy in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to delay the line of code where it says "Destroy" by 2 seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float bounceSpeed = 13f;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")){
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * bounceSpeed;
            
            
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not c++

Comment: There is a build-in delay already ... [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float bounceSpeed = 13f;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")){
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * bounceSpeed;
            
            
            Destroy(collision.gameObject, 2f);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity does support by itself delaying a destroy event. This can be done by passing a float value as an argument to the Destroy() function. So it looks like this:

```
Destroy(collision.gameObject, 2f);
```

Other ways of achieving the same behavior can be using something like the Invoke function with a delay, but it isn't necessary to do that, as Unity already provides you with a simpler way of doing that.

One important note is you should have looked into the Unity scripting API before asking this question. You can find the Unity scripting API easily with a google search. It's also a good practice to write the version of Unity you are using, so it's something like that "Unity scripting API 2020.3f" (assuming 2020.3f is the version you use). The API includes info about all Unity built-in components and classes.

Answer (score -1):

To delay the destruction of the enemy GameObject by 2 seconds, you can use the Destroy method along with the Destroy function that Unity provides. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired delay:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class enemyDestroyer : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private float bounceSpeed = 13f;
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.up * bounceSpeed;
    
                // Delay the destruction by 2 seconds
                StartCoroutine(DelayedDestroy(collision.gameObject));
            }
        }
    
        private IEnumerator DelayedDestroy(GameObject objToDestroy)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); // Wait for 2 seconds
            Destroy(objToDestroy);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a build-in delay already ... [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) .. no need for a coroutine at all